# Am trying to get the average of a list from a text file

Tags: python, list

[This the link to see the image of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mn7yw.png)   [I need help with feature one, click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FK8K.png)For some reason when I print out the average of the list, it only shows the number from the text file. I don't know where my mistake is. I think the issue might be when am appending the list.

```
f = open("votes.txt")
lines = f.read().split('\n')
issueA = {}
voteAa = {}
voteBa = {}


while(True):



  for line in lines:
    col = line.split(' ')
    issue = col[0]
    voteA = float(col[1])
    voteB = float(col[2])

    if voteA in voteAa:
        voteAa[issue].append(voteA)
    else:
        voteAa[issue] = [voteA]

    if voteB in voteBa:
        voteBa[issue].append(voteB)
    else:
        voteBa[issue] = [voteB]

  choice = int(input("Which choice? "))

  if choice == 1:
    for issue in voteAa:

        sumVote = sum(voteAa[issue])
        avg = sumVote / len(voteAa[issue])
        print("avg is ",sumVote)
```

Comment: Not clear why you need a while loop. Can you please show the file in your post?

Comment: ```sumVote = sum(voteAa.values())```

Comment: How many elements you expect have per issue in voteAa[2] ?

Comment: Theres 40 elements for voteAa @Serge

Comment: why are you doing `voteA in voteAa`, there are could be more than `1` or `0` or `-1` right

Comment: true but am completely lost, would you recommend any other way? @ArunmainthanKamalanathan

Comment: did you do the first part where you will create 3 arrays?

Comment: yea they are issue, voteAa, and voteBa

Comment: If you can have repetitions of issues like issue 1 first line and line 23 issue 2 line 20 and 40... use `if issue in VoteAa:`

Comment: A congressman will vote only once per issue right?

Comment: the numbers represent the congressman voted -1 = Nay, 1 = Yea, and 0 = missed the vote. Can you guys look at the images if its possible, its kind of hard to explain it

Comment: correct @ArunmainthanKamalanathan

Answer (score 0):

Since you need average by issue 
remove `for issue` loop 
and compute average in one line with special mean function like below

```
avg = mean(voteAa.values())
```

or, if you prefer keep it close to your code

```
sumVote = sum(voteAa.values())
avg = sumVote / len(voteAa)
```

also correct print line to

```
print("avg is ", avg)
```

Also you should just collect votes not need for if in the first loop.

So resulting script is

```
f = open("votes.txt")
lines = f.read().split('\n')
issueA = {}
voteAa = {}
voteBa = {}

for line in lines:
    col = line.split()
    issue = col[0]
    voteA = float(col[1])
    voteB = float(col[2])

    voteAa[issue] = voteA

sumVote = sum(voteAa.values())
avg = sumVote / len(voteAa)
print("avg is ", avg)
```

I tried to keep close to your original code, and did not say replace dictionaries with arrays, it could be simplified even further if you like, say with pandas or even standard https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: yup. per issue? then try what I said

Comment: so I should delete the for issue loop completely?@Serge

Comment: and other guy right, it might be better use arrays than dictionaries (simpler data structure, perhaps faster)

Comment: Also the question is explicitly asking to create 3 arrays.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
f = open("votes.txt")
lines = f.read().split('\n')
issues = []
voteAa = []
voteBa = []



for line in lines:
  col = line.split(' ')
  issue = col[0]
  voteA = float(col[1])
  voteB = float(col[2])

  issues.append(issue)
  voteAa.append(voteA)
  voteBa.append(voteB)


avgA = voteAa.count(0)/len(issues) * 1.0
avgB = voteBa.count(0)/len(issues) * 1.0

if (avgA > avgB):
    print('B higher than A'
elif (avgB > avbA):
    print('A higher than B')
```

Comment: you just need an array of items,  isnt it? is there any reason you need a dict?

Comment: I think we do need arrays because I need the averages for both congress man A and B, I think you look at the second image which has the problem in detail.

Comment: what you defined is not array, `issueA = {}  <= this is a dict` , `issues = []  <= this is an array`

Comment: let me know if you have any questions

Comment: final edit, reversed the print statements, because if congressmanA has more missing votes than B, A's performance is poorer than B